# Auto-populate an existing column based on another column using data from different list

Tags: list, lookup-column, column, data

I have two lists filled with data (*listA* and *listB*). *A* is a list of people with column '*DepartmentName*' in it. *B* is a list of departments with columns '*DepartmentName*' and '*Building*'.

I want to create a column '*Building*' in *listA* and auto-populate it based on '*DepartmentName*' (when it matches in *A* and *B*) using data from column '*Building*' in *listB*.

(I'd have a list of people with their departments and their buildings in *A*).

It would be enough for me to simply display the additional 'Building' column in listA.

I've tried using lookup column but it seems like I have to use it while creating an item (I need to display the additional column for already existing data). It also seems like there's no way of creating a condition in calculated column that would resolve my problem.

Is there any way I could do this?

Best Regards,
Ania

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you simply wish to show additional columns through the `DepartmentName` lookup column on `listA`. Open its column settings page and there will be a section called `Add a column to show each of these additional fields`. Select `Building` from the available columns and then save. You will now be able to view the `building` column on `listA`.

**Check also the following articles that may match your requirement.**

- [Auto Populate Field Values based on Lookup Selection In SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/autofill-list-form-fields-based-on-lookup-selection-in-sharepoint/)
- [SharePoint Auto Populate Column based on another Column](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-populate-column-based-on-another-column/)

Comment: Thanks!
I managed to create a column that updates when a new item is created, but it still doesn't work for items that exist already.

Comment: I tried to work it around by using a workflow that changes the fields value, but workflows have to be started manually or on creation/modification. So the problem now is to edit all the items at once to trigger all the workflows. I created an additional column for that and tried to edit it using access, but there's a problem with the access query and lookup columns (there are too many of them which stops the query even though the column I try to update isn't a lookup)